# bash remove subdirectories based on age but keep last X

Tags: linux, bash

I've found several questions similar to this and detailed answers for each but none of them quite seem to work for me.

Here's what I have. I'm only looking at directories here, ignoring files.

```
dir1/1/
dir1/2/
dir1/3/
dir2/1/
dir2/2/
dir2/3/
```

There are a lot of directories here (~800), and many of them have a lot of subdirectories (some over 2,000).

NOTE: subdirectories will never contain spaces or any special characters, they are just numbers, so I'm fine with parsing the output of `ls`.

What I need to do is to remove all subdirectories that are X days old, but I always have to keep the last N directories. In this case, remove everything that's 90 days old but always keep the last 10 directories.

I can do one or the other, but can't seem to get both. This command gets me all subdirectories that are over 90 days old:

`find * -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -type d -mtime +90`

And this command gets me all but the last ten subdirectories in each directory:

`for d in $(ls); do ls -t $d | tail -n +11; done`

What I need however is a combination of the two: remove all directories that are older than 90 days but keep the last 10.

NOTE: I know neither of the commands above actually do any deleting, I'm just trying to get it to output the correct results before adding `rm` to `xargs` or `-exec`.

Any suggestions?

Thanks @totoro and @daniel Azuelos for the answer, this worked for me:

```
 for d in *; do
   if [ -d "$d" ]; then
      marker=$(ls -td "$d/*/" | sed -n '10p')
      find "$d" -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -type d -mtime +90 ! -newer "$d"/"$marker"
   fi
 done
```

Comment: The newest 10 of the ones 90+ days old, or just keep the 10 newest of them all?

Comment: Every dir should contain the ten newest subdirs. If there are more that are under 90 days, those need to stay as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Daniel's in work:

```
for d in *; do
    if [ -d "$d" ]; then
        marker=$(ls -t "$d" | sed -n '10p')
        find "$d" -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -type d -mtime +90 ! -newer "$d/$marker"
    fi
done
```

**UPDATE**

Handle (ignore) files in folders (thanks to @sjsam):

```
for d in *; do
    if [ -d "$d" ]; then
        marker=$(ls -td "$d"/*/ 2> /dev/null | sed -n '10p')
        if [ -n "$marker" ]; then
            find "$d" -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -type d -mtime +90 ! -newer "$marker"
        fi
    fi
done
```

Comment: seems close but two problems: one is it seems to list all but the oldest ten directories (90 days old) rather than only the ten last directories. The other problem is that it's extremely slow, normally doing a find here takes about 10-15 seconds, this took a couple minutes..

Comment: Alright, see @daniel's answer then, regarding the marker. I thought it was last 10 of the 90+ :-)

Comment: @Martin Updated using Daniel's method.

Comment: Thanks @totoro and Daniel bingo! Problem was that I was missing $d/$marker

Comment: Hey @totoro if you change it to be `-newer $d/$marker` I'll mark your answer as correct. Thanks again both of you!

Answer (score 4):

```
ls -t | sed -n '10p'
```

will provide you the name of the 10th more recent file or directory.
This will be your *time_marker*.

`find ... -mtime +90 ! -newer`*time_marker*`...`

will do the rest.

Comment: Not sure how to make this work. I tried looping through each directory and putting the time_marker in backticks but it says "subfolder_name" no such file or dir. I did this: `for d in *; do find $d -mindepth ... -mtime +90 ! -newer $(ls -t $d | sed -n '10p'); done`

Comment: I suggest you to split the problem to solve it: `ls` alone, `find` alone, then use a variable or `$(...)` construct to glue the 2 together.

Answer (score 1):

Below script saved in your base directory :

```
#!/bin/bash
marker="$(readlink -m $(ls -dt */ | sed -n '10p'))"
find . -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -type d  -not -newer "$marker" -exec rm -R {} \;
```

should do it.

This has one difference from @daniel-azuelos answer.  I used `-dt` option with ls otherwise you would be getting wrong marker as files will also be listed.

`readlink -m` follows the symlink which is not really needed here.

Note : `10p` with `sed` is just gambling as the results may not always be accurate when you create directories in batch with `mkdir` for testing.

Courtesy : @daniel-azuelos for the idea.

Answer (score 0):

Using perl you can remove the last ten items as follows...

```
for d in $(ls); do ls -t $d | perl -ne 'BEGIN{@a}; push(@a, $_); END{ splice(@a, -10); for(@a){print $_;}};'
```

Or by editing the parameter to splice the first ten items ie `splice(@a, -10)` to `splice(@a, 10)`.

```
for d in $(ls); do ls -t $d | perl -ne 'BEGIN{@a}; push(@a, $_); END{ splice(@a, 10); for(@a){print $_;}};'
```

I'm sure there are shorter version than this :)

Perls `BEGIN` allows you to save all the values and once the interpreter is about to exit `END` allows you to do something, in this case we remove `10` items from the start or end of the array depending on the value passed to `splice`.

Comment: I don't know perl but that command doesn't seem to do anything (it just sits there). Should that output anything while it's running? It could be that I just didn't let it sit long enough. Thanks!

Comment: Hi @Harry that gives me all but the first ten subdirectories in each directory

Comment: You can edit the parameter to `splice` ie change 'splice(@a, -10)' to `splice(@a, 10)` to remove from the other end of the array.

Answer (score 0):

Really ugly but:

```
( ( find  ./  -mindepth 2 -maxdepth 2 -type d  -not -mtime +90 ;  find ./  -mindepth 2 -maxdepth 2 -type d  -printf "%T@ %p\n" | sort -n | tail -n +11 | sed 's/^[^ ]* //' ) | sort | uniq -d ) ; find ./ -mindepth 2 -maxdepth 2 -type d -mtime +90 ) | sort | uniq -u
```

Explanation:

Sort by timestamp, exclude top 10

```
find ./  -mindepth 2 -maxdepth 2 -type d  -printf "%T@ %p\n" | sort -n | tail -n +11 | sed 's/^[^ ]* //'
```

Concatenate the rows that should not be removed, remove the row not duplicated ( mtime < 90 )

```
( find  ./  -mindepth 2 -maxdepth 2 -type d  -not -mtime +90 ;  <CODE ABOVE> ) | sort | uniq -d
```

Concatenate the rows with mtime >90, remove the rows duplicated ( the ones in the top 10 )

```
( <CODE ABOVE>; find ./ -mindepth 2 -maxdepth 2 -type d -mtime +90 ) | sort | uniq -u
```

Comment: Hi @xvan, this seems to just output the parent directory names

Comment: Changed depths to only test subdirectories.